Thriller by Michael Jackson - "Here tonight!" Progression Question
In Michael Jackson's Thriller, theres a section of the third chorus which adds a few extra bars with a very peculiar chord progression. You can listen to it here -- the iconic "Killer, diller, chiller, thriller, here tonight!"
The song is in C# Dorian, and I believe the chord progression for this section is:
A7 - F#7 - A/B - D# - Dmaj7 - A/B.
Which would make this something like:
VI7 - IV7 - VII - II - bIImaj7 - VII.
Where does a chord progression like this come from? What is the logic behind it? Harmonizing the melody? Very odd chords that I'm not sure how to understand, but it sounds awesome in the track along w/ MJ's vocal harmonies.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Try analyzing it in A major, with Eb rather than D#.

@Aaron - Assuming the chord progression is correct, I think analyzing it in A major produces even worse results: I7 -> VI7 = V7/ii -> Iadd2 -> #IV -> IV7 -> Iadd2 has a really strange transition in it.

@Dekkadeci I - VI - I - bV - IV - I.

The notation “A/B” means “an A chord, with a B in the bass.” If that really is the right identification from an analysis standpoint, then the B is a non-chordal tone, and in Roman numeral analysis you use whatever number the A chord would be.

Analyzing it in A anything doesn't make sense, as it's clearly centered on C#.

Don't get fixated over the "C# Dorian" idea. Yes, it uses the C# Dorian sound a lot, but the A/B chord is used a lot as well and other things like A/C# that move away from to the C# Dorian sound.
Look at it primarily in terms of C# minor and sometimes E major, and modal mixing. Like a lot of songs arising from a soul/jazz background, Thriller plays around with modal interchange or modal mixtures, where the harmony around a center note is changed. Like during the C#m - F#/C# parts (with C# being used like a pedal tone), you get a C# Dorian feeling with a raised sixth scale degree A#. But then there's the A/C# chord which makes A natural. Now A is sharp, now it's natural, now it's sharp again. The mode changes, the harmony changes, it's not rigidly glued to a fixed position.
The syncopated chord stabs over "Killer, diller, chiller, thriller here tonight" A7 - F#7 - A/B - D# - Dmaj7 - A/B can be seen as VI7 - IV7 - VII - II - bIImaj7 - VII like you wrote, if you insist on thinking in terms of Roman numerals with a fixed location for the "one" chord even over constant modal mixing as what's happening in Thriller. But I'd rather think about it as a malleable, constantly changing field of harmonic possibilities. You play a chord and it changes the harmonic field, it changes the possibilities or probabilities: what could come next, what notes are sharp/natural/flat RIGHT NOW, or what we could make as a new harmonic center if we wanted to. It's like your body posture and balancing when dancing - where is your point of balance, how and where you are positioned, how you could move.
Let's look at these one by one:

A7 : this is a variation of the previous idea with the A/C# chord over "ghoul would ever dare try". Instead of the C# pedal bass it gives you an actual A chord, and even an A7 which makes G natural for a moment.
F#7 : more modal mixing, now A is sharp again.
A/B : more modal mixing, now A is natural again, and you could imagine that it's possibly moving to E major. Try playing an E major after this. Really goofy feeling.
D# : more modal mixing. It didn't leave the C# minor idea after all. Maybe it's kind of a secondary dominant, going to do a D# -> G#7 -> C#m???
D : more modal mixing. Maybe it's moving not to E major, but G major? Or maybe D - E - F#m?? Or maybe it's going to go D - C#m.
A/B : the same thing, a standard soul/jazz thing, switching back and forth between parallel major and minor, like E major and E minor (where the previous D chord would fit). Although as you know it's never going to go to E major, this gets resolved to a C# minor chord instead.

So where do things like this "come from"? From a composer or arranger's acquired bag of tricks, from tradition and habits. Maybe by tossing a coin.
Again, don't be confused by the fact that you happen to know how the tune actually goes. At each chord change, think about the possibilities, things that you could do, if you were improvising the chords.

I finally listened to the "Thriller" passage - and one of its shorter twins earlier in the song - and:

I have doubts the A/B chord labels are completely correct - the B in the bass is so loud that it makes the chord sound like a B chord instead of an A chord, and the next loudest note is an E (for the first appearance) or an F♯ (for the second appearance), to the point that any A is really hard to hear at best.
The "Thriller" passage in question sounds like it is stretching any notion of key in its earlier twins and (temporarily) throwing that out the window with extensions of the sequence of previous chords. Discarding the initial A7 - F♯7 - "A/B" = B11no3 from earlier twins as the same rough VI7 - IV7 - "VIadd9" = VII11no3 as before, analyzing the remaining D#(7?) - Dmaj7 - "A/B" = B11no3 chords as the harmonically crazy II(7?) (= V(7?)/V) - ♭II7 - "VIadd9" = VII11no3 actually makes sense at this point to hammer home that this chord progression loses the previous sense of key (at least until the second "A/B").


A/B is an idiomatic way of notating a commonly used 11 sus4 something chord that's used essentially like a fancy B7. It's a soul/smooth jazz idiom. The people who're in the culture where it's used know how to play it and what it means, so for all practical intents and purposes it's correct, just like it's correct to say "how do you do", even without actually wanting to know how one "does". A/B is written instead of "B11 (omit 3)", because that's how it's played in practice and it's more understandable for a random accompanist. Chord symbols are instructions for accompaniment after all.

@piiperiReinstateMonica - The problem is that, just like the Andy Bonner comment on the OP, labelling the chord as A/B makes analyzing it as an A chord instead of a B chord really tempting, especially without listening to the song.

@piiperiReinstateMonica A/B might be more convenient for playing, but B9sus4 is perhaps better for harmonic analysis.
